# How do I fix amavis mysql warning "execute failed: Unknown column 'rseqnum'"

Tags: mysql, amavisd-new

If you are using amavisd-new with a SQL server (Docs are located in /usr/share/doc/amavisd-new) you will see error messages similar to this:

```
(!)WARN save_info_final: sql exec: err=1054, 42S22,                     \
  DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Unknown column 'rseqnum'               \
  in 'field list' at (eval 135)
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with amavisd-new-2.7.0, three fields need to be added
to table msgrcpt and one to table msgs:

```
ALTER TABLE msgrcpt ADD rseqnum     integer  DEFAULT 0   NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE msgrcpt ADD content     char(1)  DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE msgrcpt ADD is_local    char(1)  DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE msgs    ADD originating char(1)  DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL;
```

Enter the above SQL statements to update the database that amavisd-new uses; usually `mail_amavis`. e.g.:  `mysql -u <auth-user> -p mail_amavis`to do so.